# How to ignore ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 when using .map and .collect methods?

Tags: java

I want to ignore the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0. I want to go further if the port1[1] is not empty.

```
if (port1[1] != null){
    String[] inputArray1=port1[1].split(",");

    Map meInputs1 = Stream.of(inputArray1)
                          .map(s -> s.split(":",2))
                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0],  
                                   Collectors.mapping(s -> s[1], 
                                   Collectors.toList()))); 
    }
```

I get this error at the first line of my code

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

How do I skip this if the item I am pointing to is empty?

Comment: 1. Don't ignore any exceptions in Java. 2. Please show us what `port1` contains

Comment: I don't see a loop.

Comment: @TheLostMind Currently its empty . In other cases I will have a string with key value pairs.

Comment: If `port1[1]` is not to cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, then `port.length` must be 2 or greater.  So you avoid the exception by amending your condition to include a test of that condition: `if (port1.length >= 2 && port[1] != null)...` Assuming, of course, that it's `if(port1[1] != null)` that's throwing the exception...

Comment: verify what the value of `port1[1]` is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *"ignore ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0"* by adding conditional logic to prevent it from happening.

In this case, it means that you want to check if result of `s.split(":",2)` is an array of 2 values, and ignore/skip if not. You do that by calling [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Map<Object, List<Object>> meInputs1 = Stream.of(inputArray1)
        .map(s -> s.split(":",2))
        .filter(s -> s.length >= 2) // ignore entries in inputArray1 without a ':'
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0],
                 Collectors.mapping(s -> s[1],
                 Collectors.toList())));
```